# Take random sample by group

Tags: r, dataframe, sample

I have a data frame made by almost 50,000 rows spread in 15 different IDs (every ID has thousands of observations). Data frame looks like:

```
        ID  Year    Temp    ph
1       P1  1996    11.3    6.80
2       P1  1996    9.7     6.90
3       P1  1997    9.8     7.10
...
2000    P2  1997    10.5    6.90
2001    P2  1997    9.9     7.00
2002    P2  1997    10.0    6.93
```

I want to take 500 random rows for every ID (so 500 for P1, 500 for P2,....) and create a new df. I try:

```
new_df<-df[df$ID %in% sample(unique(dfID),500),]
```

But it takes randomly one ID, while I need 500 random rows for every ID.

Comment: If you came here for the reverse question of using all rows but sampling from some of the 15 different IDs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37149649/randomly-sample-groups

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(ID),function(x) x[sample(nrow(x),500),])
```

Answer (score 93):

This is available as the [`slice_sample`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html) function in `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)
new_df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice_sample(n=500)
```

In older versions of R, the function was called [`sample_n`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/sample_n.html), which has been deprecated.

Comment: Worked well on large data frame.

Comment: Did not work when called from a for loop within a function. Works perfectly outside the function. Anyone has a hint why?

Comment: Non-Standard Evaluation/Standard Evaluation issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34187076/5088194

Comment: only issue I had with this solution is you can only take the maximum number of samples of the smallest group. Say one ID has 499 rows, but you need 500 for all others, it will throw an error.

Comment: Just an FYI since dplyr verbs change a lot: in dplyr v.1 this is superceded by `slice_sample`

Answer (score 13):

Here is one approach in base R.

First, the prerequisite sample data to work with:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:3, each = 5), matrix(rnorm(45), ncol = 3))
mydf
#    ID         X1          X2          X3
# 1   1 -0.6264538 -0.04493361  1.35867955
# 2   1  0.1836433 -0.01619026 -0.10278773
# 3   1 -0.8356286  0.94383621  0.38767161
# 4   1  1.5952808  0.82122120 -0.05380504
# 5   1  0.3295078  0.59390132 -1.37705956
# 6   2 -0.8204684  0.91897737 -0.41499456
# 7   2  0.4874291  0.78213630 -0.39428995
# 8   2  0.7383247  0.07456498 -0.05931340
# 9   2  0.5757814 -1.98935170  1.10002537
# 10  2 -0.3053884  0.61982575  0.76317575
# 11  3  1.5117812 -0.05612874 -0.16452360
# 12  3  0.3898432 -0.15579551 -0.25336168
# 13  3 -0.6212406 -1.47075238  0.69696338
# 14  3 -2.2146999 -0.47815006  0.55666320
# 15  3  1.1249309  0.41794156 -0.68875569
```

Second, the sampling:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(mydf, mydf$ID), 
               function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), 3), ]))
#      ID         X1          X2         X3
# 1.2   1  0.1836433 -0.01619026 -0.1027877
# 1.1   1 -0.6264538 -0.04493361  1.3586796
# 1.5   1  0.3295078  0.59390132 -1.3770596
# 2.10  2 -0.3053884  0.61982575  0.7631757
# 2.9   2  0.5757814 -1.98935170  1.1000254
# 2.8   2  0.7383247  0.07456498 -0.0593134
# 3.13  3 -0.6212406 -1.47075238  0.6969634
# 3.12  3  0.3898432 -0.15579551 -0.2533617
# 3.15  3  1.1249309  0.41794156 -0.6887557
```

---

There is also `strata` from the `sampling` package, which is convenient when you want to sample different sizes from each group:

```
# install.packages("sampling")
library(sampling)
set.seed(1)
x <- strata(mydf, "ID", size = c(2, 3, 2), method = "srswor")
getdata(mydf, x)
#            X1          X2         X3 ID ID_unit Prob Stratum
# 2   0.1836433 -0.01619026 -0.1027877  1       2  0.4       1
# 5   0.3295078  0.59390132 -1.3770596  1       5  0.4       1
# 6  -0.8204684  0.91897737 -0.4149946  2       6  0.6       2
# 8   0.7383247  0.07456498 -0.0593134  2       8  0.6       2
# 9   0.5757814 -1.98935170  1.1000254  2       9  0.6       2
# 14 -2.2146999 -0.47815006  0.5566632  3      14  0.4       3
# 15  1.1249309  0.41794156 -0.6887557  3      15  0.4       3
```

Answer (score 13):

In case you have big datasets, a `data.table` solution could go like this:

```r
library(data.table)

# Generate 26 mil rows random data
set.seed(2023-08-11) # anchor the  random number generator (RNG) state for reproducibility 
dt <- data.table(c1 = sample(length(LETTERS)*10^6), 
                 c2 = sample(LETTERS, replace = TRUE))

# For each letter, sample 500 rows
set.seed(2023-08-11) # anchor the RNG again, as we use `sample` again
dt_sample <- dt[, .SD[sample(x = .N, size = 500)], by = c2]

# We indeed sampled 500 rows for each letter
dt_sample[, .N, by = c2][order(c2)]
#>     c2   N
#>  1:  A 500
#>  2:  D 500
#>  3:  G 500
#>  4:  I 500
#>  5:  M 500
#>  6:  N 500
#>  7:  O 500
#>  8:  P 500
#>  9:  Q 500
#> 10:  R 500
#> 11:  S 500
#> 12:  T 500
#> 13:  U 500
#> 14:  V 500
#> 15:  W 500
#> 16:  Y 500
#> 17:  Z 500
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

In case your data is unbalanced in the sense that some groups happen to be smaller (as number of rows) than your desired sample size, then you need to set a defensive trick like sample size should be `min(500, .N)` - see [sample random rows within each group in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16289234/5193830). So like:

`dt[, .SD[sample(x = .N, size = min(500, .N))], by = c2]`

Comment: This is great! Should I set the seed also before calling `dt_sample <- dt[, .SD[sample(x = .N, size = 500)], by = c2]` to have it reproducible?

Comment: @umbe1987, yes, it is safer/good practice to have the seed set again. Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

An approach if on of the IDs is < 500.  Here I used the mtcars set:

```
n <- 8
df <- mtcars
df$ID <- df$cyl

FUN <- function(x, n) {
    if (length(x) <= n) return(x)
    x[x %in% sample(x, n)]
}

df[unlist(lapply(split(1:nrow(df), df$ID), FUN, n = 8)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elegant solution based on `data.table`. You can randomly draw IDs from a panel data set (balanced or unbalanced) in three simple steps:

**Step 1:** Store unique IDs from your original data set in a vector (my data set is called "main" and the identifier is called "id"):

```
ids <- unique(main$id)
```

**Step 2:** Randomly draw IDs from the vector from step 1. In the example below, I randomly draw 50 IDs from the vector "ids" and store them in the new vector "draw":

```
draw <- ids %>% sample(50)
```

**Step 3:** Subset rows in your original data set based on matches with the IDs drawn in step 2.

```
rsample <- main[main$id %in% draw, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata1 is your original data(not tested)

mydata2<- split(mydata1,mydata1$ID)
names(mydata2)<-paste0("mydata2",1:length(levels(ID))) 
mysample<-Map(function(x) x[sample((1:nrow(x)),size=500,replace=FALSE),], mydata2)

library(plyr)# for rbinding the mysample
ldply(mysample)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not very elegant solution, but it may work.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
f <- list()
for(i in unique(df1$ID)){
 f[[i]] <- df1[id == i][sample(.N,(500))]
  }
 dfnew <- rbindlist(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table) #1
df <- data.table(df) #2
df[,group_num := sample(2,.N,replace = TRUE,prob = c(500,.N-500)/.N),by = "ID"] #3
df_sample = df[group_num == 1,] #4
```

or you can change line #3 and #4 to:

```
df[,random_num := sample(.N,.N),by="ID"]
df_sample  = df[random_num <=500,]
```