# Error when using dplyr inside of a function

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyeval

I'm trying to put together a function that creates a subset from my original data frame, and then uses dplyr's SELECT and MUTATE to give me the number of large/small entries, based on the sum of the width and length of sepals/petals.

```
filter <- function (spp, LENGTH, WIDTH) {
  d <- subset (iris, subset=iris$Species == spp) # This part seems to work just fine
  large <- d %>%                       
    select (LENGTH, WIDTH) %>%   # This is where the problem arises.
    mutate (sum = LENGTH + WIDTH) 
  big_samples <- which(large$sum > 4)
 return (length(big_samples)) 
}
```

Basically, I want the function to return the number of large flowers. However, when I run the function I get the following error -

```
filter("virginica", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")

 Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  LENGTH
*  WIDTH
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dplyr` functions use non-standard evaluation. That is why you do not have to quote your variable names when you do something like `select(mtcars, mpg)`, and why `select(mtcars, "mpg")` doesn't work. When you use `dplyr` in functions, you will likely want to use "standard evaluation". See `vignette("nse")` for more details.

Comment: but why the function?

Comment: A quick and dirty solution is to change `select(LENGTH, WIDTH) %>%` to `select(get(LENGTH), get(WIDTH)) %>%`. However, you should really be using `select_()` and `mutate_()` in your functions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As of dplyr 0.7.0 you can use tidy eval to accomplish this.

See http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html for more details.

```
filter_big <- function(spp, LENGTH, WIDTH) {
  LENGTH <- enquo(LENGTH)                    # Create quosure
  WIDTH  <- enquo(WIDTH)                     # Create quosure

  iris %>% 
    filter(Species == spp) %>% 
    select(!!LENGTH, !!WIDTH) %>%            # Use !! to unquote the quosure
    mutate(sum = (!!LENGTH) + (!!WIDTH)) %>% # Use !! to unquote the quosure
    filter(sum > 4) %>% 
    nrow()
}

filter_big("virginica", Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)

> filter_big("virginica", Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
[1] 50
```

Answer (score 22):

You are running into NSE/SE problems, see [the vignette for more info](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).

Briefly, `dplyr` uses a non standard evaluation (NSE) of names, and passing names of columns into functions breaks it, without using the standard evaluation (SE) version.

The SE versions of the `dplyr` functions end in _. You can see that `select_` works nicely with your original arguments.

However, things get more complicated when using functions. We can use `lazyeval::interp` to convert most function arguments into column names, see the conversion of the `mutate` to `mutate_` call in your function below and more generally, the help: `?lazyeval::interp`

Try:

```
filter <- function (spp, LENGTH, WIDTH) {
    d <- subset (iris, subset=iris$Species == spp) 
    large <- d %>%                       
        select_(LENGTH, WIDTH) %>%  
        mutate_(sum = lazyeval::interp(~X + Y, X = as.name(LENGTH), Y = as.name(WIDTH))) 
    big_samples <- which(large$sum > 4)
    return (length(big_samples)) 
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution to the problem. Just out of curiosity, would anyone have an easier or simpler function that could be used achieve the same outcome?

Comment: here's what I would do: `myfun <- function(species, col1, col2){
  sum(iris$Species ==species & (iris[[col1]]+iris[[col2]]) > 4)
}`

Answer (score 5):

If quosure and quasiquotation are too much for you, use either `.data[[ ]]` or `rlang` `{{ }}` ([curly curly](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/)) instead. See [Hadley Wickham's 5min video on tidy evaluation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nERXS3ssntw) and (maybe) [Tidy evaluation section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#tidy-evaluation) in Hadley's Advanced R book for more information.

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

filter_data <- function(df, spp, LENGTH, WIDTH) {
  res <- df %>% 
    filter(Species == spp) %>% 
    select(.data[[LENGTH]], .data[[WIDTH]]) %>%        
    mutate(sum = .data[[LENGTH]] + .data[[WIDTH]]) %>% 
    filter(sum > 4) %>% 
    nrow()
  return(res)
}

filter_data(iris, "virginica", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
#> [1] 50


filter_rlang <- function(df, spp, LENGTH, WIDTH) {
  res <- df %>% 
    filter(Species == spp) %>% 
    select({{LENGTH}}, {{WIDTH}}) %>%        
    mutate(sum = {{LENGTH}} + {{WIDTH}}) %>% 
    filter(sum > 4) %>% 
    nrow()
  return(res)
}

filter_rlang(iris, "virginica", Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
#> [1] 50
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>