# How can I filter a dataframe based on (randomly selected) unique values of a column?

Tags: r, dataframe, random, dplyr, statistics

I read some articles here on how to filter based on specific values in a given column. However, what I am interested in is whether I can filter randomly selected unique values of a column. To better understand my question, please consider the following sample dataframe:

```
MeasurementPoint <- c(1,2,1,2,3,3,4,4,6,7,6,7)
subject <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4)
MeasurementMethod <- c("A","A", "B", "B", "A","B", "A","B","A","A", "B","B")
value <- c(-0.06, 0.11,-0.11,-0.01.-0.13, 0.02, -0.08, 0.09, 0.05, 0.04, -0.03, -0.02)
df1 <- data.frame(MeasurementPoint, subject,MeasurementMethod, value)
df1
```

```
 MeasurementPoint subject MeasurementMethod value
         1            1            A        -0.06
         2            1            A         0.11
         1            1            B        -0.11
         2            1            B        -0.01
         3            2            A        -0.13
         3            2            B         0.02
         4            3            A        -0.08
         4            3            B         0.09
         6            4            A         0.05
         7            4            A         0.04
         6            4            B        -0.03
         7            4            B        -0.02
```

Some **values** are measured on different subjects with two different **MeasurementMethod** and on different **MeasurementPoint**s, e.g. multiple spots on their body.

Some subjects have more than one **MeasurementPoints** like subject #1 and #4. The rest have only one **MeasurementPoint** on their bodies, and only the **MeasurementMethod** varies for them (subject #2 and #3).

I would like to filter only one **MeasurementPoint** per subject and leave the rest. This selection should be "randomly" done. And as an example the follwoing dataframe would be an outcome of interest:

```
  MeasurementPoint subject MeasurementMethod value
                2       1                 A  0.11
                2       1                 B -0.01
                3       2                 A -0.13
                3       2                 B  0.02
                4       3                 A -0.08
                4       3                 B  0.09
                6       4                 A  0.05
                6       4                 B -0.03
```

Please note that the selection of **MeasurementPoint** = 2 for the first subject and **MeasurementPoint** = 6 for the last subject should happen randomly.

Comment: I think you need "group by column(s) get sample row(s)" see if this post helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18258690/680068

Comment: Hi @zx8754 thanks for your comment! It's not duplicate since in that post the goal is to pick a definite number of observations (500) per ID, but I would like to randomly select a **MeasurementPoint** per **subject** and keep them all.

Comment: using `new_df <- df1 %>% group_by(subject) %>% slice_sample(n=1)` I do not get what I want. However, @benson23 left an answer which generates what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `group_by` the `subject` column, and `filter` rows that match the random `MeasurementPoint` value generated by `sample`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  filter(MeasurementPoint == sample(MeasurementPoint, 1))

# A tibble: 8 × 4
# Groups:   subject [4]
  MeasurementPoint subject MeasurementMethod value
             <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl>
1                1       1 A                 -0.06
2                1       1 B                 -0.11
3                3       2 A                 -0.13
4                3       2 B                  0.02
5                4       3 A                 -0.08
6                4       3 B                  0.09
7                6       4 A                  0.05
8                6       4 B                 -0.03
```

Comment: If the MeasurementPoint has a duplicated value, this will return both rows. Not a single row.

Comment: @zx8754 If you take a look at the OP's desired outcome, it's exactly what the OP wants. Also, I disagree it's a duplicate of the post in your comment, and I disagree `slice_sample` can do the job in this case

Comment: I see, you are right, apologies, I misread the question.