# Subset a data.table given the row index for each group

Tags: r, data.table

This seems like a trivial question that I can't seem to find a solution for:

Consider the two `data.tables`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
                 val = c(10,20,30,10,20,30))

dt1 <- data.table(id = c(1,2),
                  V1 = c(2,1))
```

How do I subset `dt`, where `dt1` tells me the row number (`V1`) of the grouped `id` I need to subset?

For example, here the result will be

```
#    id val
# 1:  1  20
# 2:  2  10
```

---

**Update**

A quick bit of benchmarking on the proposed solutions

```
library(data.table)
s <- 100000
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(id = rep(seq(1:s), each=10),
                 val = rnorm(n = s*10, 0, 1))

dt1 <- data.table(id = seq(1:s),
                  V1 = sample(1:10, s, replace=T))


library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(

  akrun = { dt[dt1, on='id'][, .SD[1:.N==V1] ,id] },

  david = { dt[dt1, val[i.V1], on = 'id', by = .EACHI] },

  symbolix = { dt[, id_seq := seq(1:.N), by=id][dt1, on=c(id_seq = "V1", "id") , nomatch=0] },

   times = 5

 )
#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
#    akrun 17809.51370 17887.89037 18005.32357 18043.80279 18130.78978 18154.62118     5
#    david    48.17367    53.76436    53.79004    54.69096    55.59657    56.72467     5
 #symbolix   507.67312   511.23492   562.59743   571.31160   579.61228   643.15525     5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to use `by = .EACHI` in order to subset `val` while joing

```
dt[dt1, val[i.V1], on = 'id', by = .EACHI]
#    id V1
# 1:  1 20
# 2:  2 10
```

If you have more columns there, you could use `.SD[i.V1]` instead.

---

As a side note, in data.table v >= 1.9.8 the `.SD[val]` operation is scheduled to be fully optimized to use GForce- so hold tight.

Comment: So is `.SD` already optimized in 1.9.7 or not yet? I'm confused.

Comment: @docendodiscimus it is optimized for cases when you explicitly use a positive integer such as `.SD[2L]` but not optimized if you pass it as a variable as in `val <- 2L ; .SD[val]`. This should be fixed in v 1.9.8 (hopefully).

Comment: very nice. I was struggling with a `.EACHI` solution so I'm glad to see this!

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to `join`  `on` 'id' and then do the subset

```
dt[dt1, on='id'][, .SD[1:.N==V1] ,id][,V1:=NULL][]
#   id val
#1:  1  20
#2:  2  10
```

Comment: On a similar theme, then, perhaps `dt[, id_seq := seq(1:.N), by=id][dt1, on=c(id_seq = "V1", "id") , nomatch=0]`  (to avoid the `.SD` allocation) ?