# Select random rows from duplicate IDS

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a dataset where I have students ratings of teachers. Some students rated the same teacher more than once.
What I would like to do with the data is to subset it with the following criteria:

1) Keep any unique student Ids and ratings

2) In cases where students rated a teacher twice keep only 1 rating, but to select which rating to keep randomly.

3) If possible I'd like to be able to run the code in a munging script at the top of every analysis file and ensure that the dataset created is exaclty the same for each analysis (set seed?).

```
# data
student.id <- c(1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8,9)
teacher.id <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
rating <- c(100,99,89,100,99,87,24,52,100,99,89,79,12)
df <- data.frame(student.id,teacher.id,rating)
```

Thanks for any guidance for how to move forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each student.id is only applied to one teacher, you could use the following method.

```
# get a list containing data.frames for each student
myList <- split(df, df$student.id)

# take a sample of each data.frame if more than one observation or the single observation
# bind the result together into a data.frame
set.seed(1234)
do.call(rbind, lapply(myList, function(x) if(nrow(x) > 1) x[sample(nrow(x), 1), ] else x))
```

This returns

```
  student.id teacher.id rating
1          1          1    100
2          2          1     89
3          3          1     99
4          4          2     87
5          5          2     24
6          6          2     52
7          7          2     99
8          8          2     79
9          9          2     12
```

---

If the same student.id rates multiple teachers, then this method requires the construction of a new variable with the `interaction` function:

```
# create new interaction variable
df$stud.teach <- interaction(df$student.id, df$teacher.id)

myList <- split(df, df$stud.teach)
```

then the remainder of the code is identical to that above.

---

A potentially faster method is to use the `data.table` library and `rbindlist`.

```
library(data.table)
# convert into a data.table
setDT(df)

myList <- split(df, df$stud.teach)

# put together data.frame with rbindlist
rbindlist(lapply(myList, function(x) if(nrow(x) > 1) x[sample(nrow(x), 1), ] else x))
```

Comment: what would change if a student rated multiple teachers? i can update my data.

Comment: The split would have to be on a variable that interacts the teacher and the student ids. See my updated answer.

Comment: Fantastic. That helps a lot! Is there a way to speed that code up? I have 100,000 IDS, so it is quite slow to converge to a solution in the final do.call or is this as fast as it gets?

Comment: I added a `data.table` method that may speed things up a bit.

Comment: These are fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done much faster using `data.table`. Your question is equivalent to sampling rows from within groups, see

[Sample random rows within each group in a data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289182/sample-random-rows-within-each-group-in-a-data-table)