# R data.table - sample by group with different sampling proportion

Tags: r, data.table, oversampling

I would like to efficiently make a random sample by group from a `data.table`, but it should be possible to sample a different proportion for each group.

If I wanted to sample fraction `sampling_fraction` from each group, i could get inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289182/sample-random-rows-within-each-group-in-a-data-table) question and [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16289234/7064628) answer to do something like:

```
DT = data.table(a = sample(1:2), b = sample(1:1000,20))

group_sampler <- function(data, group_col, sample_fraction){
  # this function samples sample_fraction <0,1> from each group in the data.table
  # inputs:
  #   data - data.table
  #   group_col - column(s) used to group by
  #   sample_fraction - a value between 0 and 1 indicating what % of each group should be sampled
  data[,.SD[sample(.N, ceiling(.N*sample_fraction))],by = eval(group_col)]
}

# what % of data should be sampled
sampling_fraction = 0.5

# perform the sampling
sampled_dt <- group_sampler(DT, 'a', sampling_fraction)
```

But what if i wanted to sample 10% from group 1 and 50% from group 2?

Comment: How do you define which is group 1 and which is group 2

Comment: In the example above, the column 'a' has values 1 and 2. thus, group a and group 2. I think that to make sure that correct sampling fraction is assigned to each group, it might be possible to use a named vector or something like that in the input of the function. I am just not exactly sure how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.GRP` but to ensure a correct group is matched.. you might want to define `group_col` as a factor variable.

```
group_sampler <- function(data, group_col, sample_fractions) {
  # this function samples sample_fraction <0,1> from each group in the data.table
  # inputs:
  #   data - data.table
  #   group_col - column(s) used to group by
  #   sample_fraction - a value between 0 and 1 indicating what % of each group should be sampled
  stopifnot(length(sample_fractions) == uniqueN(data[[group_col]]))
  data[, .SD[sample(.N, ceiling(.N*sample_fractions[.GRP]))], keyby = group_col]
}
```

*Edit in response to chinsoon12's comment:*

It would be safer (instead of relying on correct order) to have the last line of the function:

```
data[, .SD[sample(.N, ceiling(.N*sample_fractions[[unlist(.BY)]]))], keyby = group_col]
```

And then you pass `sample_fractions` as a named vector:

```
group_sampler(DT, 'a', sample_fractions= c(x = 0.1, y = 0.9))
```

Comment: @chinsoon12 can you please make a short example what exactly you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option which uses a lookup table (and so doesn't rely on the ordering of vectors or groups).

```r
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(group = sample(1:2), val = sample(1:1000,20))

sample_props <- data.table(group = 1:2, prop = c(.1,.5))

group_sampler <- function(data, group_col, sample_props){
  # this function samples sample_fraction <0,1> from each group in the data.table
  # inputs:
  #   data - data.table with data
  #   group_col - column(s) used to group by (must be in both data.tables)
  #   sample_props - data.table with sample proportions
  ret <- merge(DT, sample_props, by = group_col)
  ret <- ret[,.SD[sample(.N, ceiling(.N*prop))], eval(group_col)]
  return(ret[,prop := NULL][])
}

# perform the sampling
group_sampler(DT, 'group', sample_props)
#>    group val
#> 1:     1 721
#> 2:     2 542
#> 3:     2 680
#> 4:     2 613
#> 5:     2 170
#> 6:     2 175
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>