# How to efficiently sample from a dataset of observed changes?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, sample

I have a large datatable with the following format:

```
library(data.table)
library(string)
library(plyr)

dt <- data.table(
  from = rep(LETTERS[1:10], each=3),
  to = rep(letters[1:3], 10),
  from_n = rep(sample(50:100, 10), each=3),
  to_n = rep(sample(1:10, 3, replace = T), 10)
)
```

I am trying split my dataset into randomly sampled test and train datasets containing 80% and 20% of the observations ("from_n") for each group ("from").

I can currently do this using a for loop and creating a randomly shuffled vector. For example:

```
test_list <- list()
train_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(unique(dt$from))){ # for each unique "from"
  sub <- dt[from == unique(dt$from)[i]] 
  n_1 <- sub$to_n[1] 
  n_2 <- sub$to_n[2]
  n_3 <- sub$to_n[3]
  n_NA <- sub$from_n[1] - sum(n_1, n_2, n_3)
  sample_vec <- sample( c( rep(NA, n_NA), # create randomised vector 
                           rep(sub$to[1], n_1),
                           rep(sub$to[2], n_2),
                           rep(sub$to[3], n_3) ) )
  
  train <- sample_vec[1:floor(length(sample_vec)*0.8)]
  train_dt <- data.table(from = sub$from,
                         to = sub$to,
                         from_n = rep(length(train), 3),
                         to_n = c(length(train[which(train == sub$to[1])]),
                                  length(train[which(train == sub$to[2])]),
                                  length(train[which(train == sub$to[3])])
                                  ))
  
  test <- sample_vec[(floor(length(sample_vec)*0.8)+1):length(sample_vec)]
  test_dt <- data.table(from = sub$from,
                         to = sub$to,
                         from_n = rep(length(test), 3),
                         to_n = c(length(test[which(test == sub$to[1])]),
                                  length(test[which(test == sub$to[2])]),
                                  length(test[which(test == sub$to[3])])
                         ))
  
  test_list[[i]] <- test_dt
  train_list[[i]] <- train_dt
}
```

However, the dataset I need to apply this to is very large, and this is too slow. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could improve performance?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `set.seed(some number of your choosing)` before your example data generation so it's reproducible and then give us a walk through of what the input and output looks like for, say, the first value of `i`. I ran the code as is, and can't make sense of what you are doing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R data.table - sample by group with different sampling proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395772/r-data-table-sample-by-group-with-different-sampling-proportion)